# Can't hit Springboot endpoint on droplet

Tags: tomcat, spring-boot, digital-ocean

I set up a Springboot Java application as well as its MySql database on the 1Gb 1Cpu Ubuntu droplet. The java app runs, and it says Tomcat has spun up on a port. When I try to hit an endpoint defined in my app's Controller though, from either Postman or Chrome, I get a message saying "{{domain}} took too long to respond." I've tried with both the Domain i've added to the droplet and the plain old API address.

My call is: `{{Domain/IP}}:{{Port #}}/{{Endpoint}}`

Am I doing something wrong? Do I need some kind of validation/authorization to hit the endpoint from another machine? The endpoints works when I run the app locally and not on the droplet.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using digital ocean to host my personal toy website built with spring boot and embedded tomcat without a problem.

Multiple things can happen:

- The http port 8080 is not opened to public. (This solved my issue)
- Firewall is preventing port 8080 from being visited.

Assuming your app is on port 8080. Change accordingly.

Comment: Tomcat says it spun up on port 9011

Comment: I know, did you open up the port 9011. The tomcat saying it is running on port 9011 does not mean the world is able to access 9011.

Comment: Nope! That’s it! I knew I was forgetting something crucial. Thanks!:D